# Understanding Keyboard LED status

Tags: c++, arduino, keyboard, led, capslock

I'm using an **Arduino Leonardo** as a keyboard (BadUSB) and I would like to get the Keyboard LEDs status (e.g. CAPS_LOCK).

Using https://github.com/NicoHood/HID/blob/master/examples/Keyboard/KeyboardLed/KeyboardLed.ino
I have managed to get it working using the following code:

*(The Keyboard library isn't included because it's somehow already included by HID-Project)*

```
#include <HID-Project.h>

#define LED_NUM_LOCK (1 << 0)       // B00000001
#define LED_CAPS_LOCK (1 << 1)      // B00000010
#define LED_SCROLL_LOCK (1 << 2)    // B00000100
#define LED_COMPOSE (1 << 3)        // B00001000
#define LED_KANA (1 << 4)           // B00010000
#define LED_POWER (1 << 5)          // B00100000
#define LED_SHIFT (1 << 6)          // B01000000
#define LED_DO_NOT_DISTURB (1 << 7) // B10000000

void setup() {
  Keyboard.begin();
  delay(500);

  if (BootKeyboard.getLeds() & LED_CAPS_LOCK) {
    // caps lock is on
    Keyboard.write("a"); // C
  } else {
    // caps lock is off
    Keyboard.write("b"); // e
  };

  Keyboard.end();
}

void loop() {}
```

The thing is I would like to **add this particular functionnality to my own library** (and avoid loading the large HID-Project library).

I belive BootKeyboard.getLeds() returns an 8-bit long number with each character representing the state of every key like defined in the code above. **However I don't understand how it's obtain because the code doesn't seems clear to me**
https://github.com/NicoHood/HID/blob/master/src/SingleReport/BootKeyboard.cpp (lines 190-192):

> uint8_t BootKeyboard_::getLeds(void) { return leds; }

as it only returns the variable leds which I guess is assigned somewhere else but I can't manage to find where and how ...

Answer (score 2):

Look at

- line53/54 (_hidReportDescriptorKeyboard definition in progmem)
- line168-172  Setting the value of the leds (0/1)
- line190-192  Getting the values

of the BootKeyboard.cpp and the definition is in the header file BootKeyboard.h

- line 78 as uint8_t

as some of the functions use the _hidReportDescriptorKeyboard you should try touse the files as base and then get rid of the functions you do not need. Ifyou have a minimalworking set you can start to refactor the code -for code analysis and dependencies you can use a static tool (snapshot) like doxygen or an IDE supporting code analysis
**EDIT**
Heres the [wiki to the Hood Loader](https://github.com/NicoHood/HoodLoader2/wiki/Overview) get some tea and time to read and learn
See those [links for details and info](https://www.manykey.org/) and [Alternative Keyboard Firmware](https://deskthority.net/viewtopic.php?t=15958) These are all [repos on github](https://github.com/topics/keyboard-firmwarehttps://github.com/topics/keyboard-firmware) you could search for

Comment: I've managed to get rid of a bunch of files    ...
    .
Now here is my current understanding of the leds variable assignement    :    .
    .
- line74 : BootKeyboard_ constructor sets it to null (B00000000)    .
- line180 : It's reassigned using the USB_RecvControl function    .
- USB_RecvControl is defined to be USBDevice.recvControl in HID-settings.h line116    .
 .
 .
But I can't manage to find the code of the USBDevice.recvControl function.    
I think it's related to "USB/PluggableUSB.h" (see line107 in HID-Settings.h) however I don't find anything that seems helpful online ...

Comment: You have probably to look into the HID sources (firmware chip) of your Leonardo or in thoseof the HIDdriver for uNO/MEGA in the Nico Lib. About HID drivers you have to search howto write an HID driver Microsoft to get the concept

Comment: Do you know how I could access the source code of the chip ? (atmega32u4) Do you have any idea where the BootKeyboard_::setup function is called and what are the variable setup and the variabletype USBSetup& ? (line107)